# ERROR setting up vagrant within an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, libvirt

I am trying to get Vagrant up and running in an Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance. I have Vagrant installed, i have a dummy vagrant box installed, I have vagrant libvirt plugin installed as well as libvirt daemons. I did a kvm check and I cant have it the CPU does not support kvm extensions. Where I'm falling down is trying to install the vagrant aws plugin. originally it failed because the json file was the wrong version I've fixed that but now the error I'm getting is as follows.

Vagrant failed to install the requested plugin because it depends
on a library which is not currently installed on this system. The
following library is required by the 'vagrant-aws' plugin:

libvirt

Please install the library and then run the command again.

If there's any more information you need please let me know, this is bugging me now!

thank you

installing vagrant, libvirt

Comment: I have since tried 
"apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libvert-dev zlib1g-dev ruby-dev"

 Now when I run

"vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws"
 
I have a new error code.

Vagrant failed to properly resolve required dependencies. These
errors can commonly be caused by misconfigured plugin installations
or transient network issues. The reported error is:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Answer (score 1):

The vagrant-aws plugin has been abandoned no longer works. Its last update was in 2018.